# Path-connectedness, does the set need to be open?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have this exerise:

> Let $X$ be locally path connected. Show that every connected **open**
>   set in X is path-connected.

But does the set need to be open? I have this theorem in the chapter:

> If $X$ is a topolocial space, each path component of X lies in a
>   component of X. If X is locally path connected, then the components
>   and the path components of X are the same.

Does not this theorem tell us directly that it holds for all subsets, not just open subsets?

Comment: What exactly is here question here?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam I am wondering that in the given exercise, do we have to assume that our connected set is open in order for the conclusion to holds, or will it hold if the set is not open aswell?

Comment: out connected set??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam The exercise is: Let X be locally path connected. Show that every connected open set A, in X, is path-connected. I am wondering if one has to require that A is open, or if it is enough that A is connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the assumption that the set is open is necessary. The plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally path-connected, and the "topologist's sine curve" $$S = \operatorname{closure} \bigl\{(x,\sin(1/x) \mid x > 0 \bigr\}$$ is connected (because it's the closure of a connected set), but it's not path-connected (a classical exercise). And since of course $S$ isn't a path component of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you cannot use the theorem you mention to say that $S$ is path-connected (and it isn't).

Comment: Thank you, I guess it may not work to do as I thought, because maybe one can prove that if a space X is locally connected, then every OPEN set A is locally connected?, but as you showed if the set A is not open(S), it may not be locally connected?

Answer (score 1):

The "topologist's sine curve" is a *nice* example. Wouldn't you rather see a nonconstructive horror?

Assuming the axiom of choice, there is a ["Bernstein decomposition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) of the plane, i.e., $\mathbb R^2$ is the union of two disjoint sets $B_1$ and $B_2,$ each of which has nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ These sets $B_i$ are famously not Lebesgue measurable, but what's pertinent to your question is that they are both connected sets, and that neither of them contains any nonconstant path.